# Rails 4 API JSON: drying up the response object

Tags: json, api, ruby-on-rails-4, response

I am creating an API that uses JSON to communicate back/forth with external view apps (Angular).  In a lot of API actions, I return a JSON response that is 99% the same as the error one below:

```
  # controller
  def create
    @record = Record.new(record_params)
    if @record.save
      @record
    else
      render json: {
        error: {
          type: "invalid_request",
          message: "Could not create record. Params: #{record_params}",
          errors: @record.errors.messages
        }
      }, status: 404
    end
  end
```

Is there a convenient way to DRY this up?  I ask specifically because I know certain methods such as the `render` only work in controller classes because they are inherited.

I'm thinking about something like the following:

```
render json: API::ErrorObject.call(@record, record_params), status: 404
```

And in that class it would be:

```
class API::ErrorObject
  self.call(object, params)
    {
      error: {
        type: "invalid_request",
        message: "Could not create record. Params: #{record_params}",
        errors: object.errors.messages
      }       
    }
  end
end
```

I think that would work, but is there an even cleaner way to abstract away some of this behavior?  The API is fairly large, so there are 30+ places where very similar code will reside.  I know that someday someone will request an addition to the API responses, and having a single place to update this would be a lot better than 30...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found so far is to bring the V back into MVC by using a tool like [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

Using this you can really DRY up your code similar to what you do using partials in ERB.